# Pass pointer to pthread of class member declared as friend

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have a class called **BaseB** which can be called from **A**.

I need to have class **A** pass a pointer to **pthread_create** of a member function in class **BaseB** that also happens to be declared as:

```
friend void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);
```

in **Class BaseB's** header under `public` accessibility. However, in the actual cpp file it is not declared as a member of that class with the class scope. Instead, it is declared as

```
void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b) { .... }
```

So how can I tell the `pthread_create` to use the `friended` class member?

I read the [C++ FAQ in Section 33](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) and it says:

> Because a member function is meaningless without an object to invoke
>   it on, you can't do this directly (if The X Window System was
>   rewritten in C++, it would probably pass references to objects around,
>   not just pointers to functions; naturally the objects would embody the
>   required function and probably a whole lot more).

??

Comment: '??' indeed -- I really have no idea what you're asking. Where does `pthread_create` come in? And `friend void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);` inside of a class does not declare a class member, it declares a function in namespace scope.

Comment: @ildjarn: ThreadedTask is the function I want to thread with `pthread_create(...)` but it is in `BaseB`. Even though `A` inherits from `BaseB` it still can't see `ThreadedTask` though it is declared as a friend.

Comment: But `ThreadedTask` is not a member of `BaseB` -- it's a free function that happens to be a friend of `BaseB`. What do you mean `A` "can't see" `ThreadedTask`?

Comment: Yes, `ThreadedTask` is declared as `friend void` in `BaseB` but it is not a member of `BaseB`. It is implemented in `BaseB.cpp` but not declared with the class scope operator in the implementation file. So basically, how do I reference it so I can tell pthread_create what function to spawn off and thread? The `pthread_create` is in the `Class A` implementation file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you have something like the following:

```
/*** baseb.hpp ***/
class BaseB {
    friend void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);

public:
    // ...
};

/*** baseb.cpp ***/
#include "baseb.hpp"
void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b) {
    // impl
}
// other BaseB definitions

/*** a.hpp ***/
struct A {
    void somefunc();
};

/*** a.cpp ***/
#include "a.hpp"
#include "baseb.hpp"
struct A {
    void somefunc() {
        // pass ThreadedTask to pthread_create
        // but where is ThreadedTask declared?
    }
};
```

What's missing is a visible declaration for `ThreadedTask`.

Either make the declaration visible in baseb.hpp, since it's now effectively a public implementation detail of `BaseB` anyway:

```
/*** baseb.hpp ***/
class BaseB;
void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);

class BaseB {
    friend void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);

public:
    // ...
};
```

Or have `A` declare it on its own, so the declaration can remain "hidden":

```
/*** a.cpp ***/
#include "a.hpp"
#include "baseb.hpp"

void ThreadedTask(BaseB* b);

struct A {
    void somefunc() {
        // pass ThreadedTask to pthread_create
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to declare `ThreadedTask` outside class declaration in `BaseB.hpp`, or cheat and declare it in the right namespace in `A.cpp`.